# rotate image with ratio

Tags: jquery, image, rotation, resize

I want to flip an image from portrait to landscape. My problem is that I want the image to fit the container based on the ratio (I dont want to stretch, but instead keep the ratio)
. Anyone know how to do that? In the fiddle the image should scale to fit when put in landscape. My width is dynamic I thought setting width 100% would fix it but it only works when the page is loaded

http://jsfiddle.net/FcQZm/114/

```
var landscape = false;

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("button").click(function(){
        if(!landscape)
        {
            $("img#testimg").css( {
               '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(270deg)',
                'width' : '100%'
            });
            landscape= true;  
         }
         else
         {
            $("img#testimg").css( {
              '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(0deg)',
              'width' : '100%'
            });
            landscape= false; 
         }        
    });
});
```

thanks

Comment: because of the way css rotation works, you need to manually reposition the image after rotating. http://jsfiddle.net/FcQZm/122/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO NEW](http://jsfiddle.net/01gv0cka/)

```
    var landscape = false;

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("button").click(function(){
        if(!landscape)
        {
            $("#testimg").css( {
               '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(270deg)',

            });

            var cw = $('#testimg')[0].clientHeight;
$('#wrapper').css('width',cw+'px');

          landscape= true;  
        }
        else
        {
            $("#testimg").css( {
               '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(0deg)',


            });
 var cw = $('#testimg')[0].clientHeight;
 var ch =  $('#testimg')[0].clientWidth;         
$('#wrapper').css('height',cw+'px');    $('#wrapper').css('width',ch+'px'); 
            landscape= false; 
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: nope, i want the image to rotate in the wrapper AND to adjust its size to the wrapper. Eg. when in landscape the width will be equal to the width of the wrapper (and the height will be calculated from the ratio of the width). When in portrait the image should fit in the wrapper